# Form size is not right(Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Not sure why my form is not looking right. Here's the code for my navigation bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header col-lg-12">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Behind the Wheel</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Traffic School</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FAQ</a>
          <div class="dropdown navbar-brand navbar-right col-md-2">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user dropdown-toggle"datatoggle="dropdown"></span>
           <form class="form-horizontal dropdown-menu" role="form">       
            <div class="form-group has-feedback" role="form">
                <label for="emailInput" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                  <label for="passwordInput" class="control-label">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
           </form>
        </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </nav>
```

And here's a pic of what happens when I click the user glyphicon to activate the drop-down, shows how screwed up my form is: [form pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRygl.png)

Comment: Note: `datatoggle` is incorrect, it is `data-toggle`, but I believe that is a copy-paste error.

Comment: Yes it was a copy-paste error. David how do I leave answered for your answer. I'm not seeing any tick to the left of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of how you can do this.

Start with the default navigation structure -> [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) as a base. As far as the form is concerned I don't believe there is an built in way to place a form inside of a `dropdown` menu so you'll most likely need to apply some CSS so it's displayed appropriately.

```css
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-form {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #222;
}
.dropdown-menu.dropdown-form label {
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-menu.dropdown-form {
    min-width: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Behind the Wheel</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Traffic School</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-form">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="search">
              <div class="form-group has-feedback" role="form">
                <label for="emailInput" class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="passwordInput" class="control-label">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
              </div>
            </form>

          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys! The padding was set to -15px for all form elements in another stylesheet. I went in to that styleesheet and changed the padding to 15px instead of -15px.